# Как убрать системные методы из stack trace?

Tags: java

Пишу свой JUnit, столкнулся с такой проблемой:
Если в тестовом методе произошла ошибка или исключение, то при щелчке по нему в дереве методов я хочу выводить stack trace в JTextPane. Получается вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть выводятся еще какие то встроенные функции, которые я не вызывал. Как этого избежать? Я пробовал метод `isNativeMethod()`
Но это не помогло. Видимо эти методы не нативные.

**UPD:**
Вот код, которым я вывожу trace:

```
StackTraceElement[] ste = e.getCause().getStackTrace();
                    for (int idx = 0; idx < ste.length; idx++) {
                        if (!ste[idx].isNativeMethod())
                            strForMessanger += ste[idx].getClassName()
                                    + "." + ste[idx].getMethodName() + "("
                                    + ste[idx].getFileName() + ":"
                                    + ste[idx].getLineNumber() + ")<br>";
                    }
```

Тут можно было бы как то по имени пакета, но по идее я не знаю какие пакеты будут использовать пользователи моей библиотеки

Comment: Eclipse, похоже, просто строки пропускает по шаблонам (в настройках, в java -> junit список)

Comment: @zRrr, а причем здесь JUnit? Я же свой JUnit пишу. Может немного непонятно было по вопросу, дополнил его

Comment: Их не стоит убирать. Конечный пользователь должен видеть всю цепочку вызовов, чтобы (теоретическая) отладка проблем с конкретной JVM не превращалась в кошмар.

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров просто пример решения аналогичной проблемы в Eclipse: отключаемый настраиваемый фильтр отображения, убирающий строки, начинающиеся с `org.junit`, `sun.reflect` и т.п.